# I want to look if an object is inside a vector using find but I can't

Tags: c++, class, object, vector

I have been trying to use `find` to look for an object inside a `vector` but it is telling me to overload an operator and I don´t know how

¿How can I overload the operator `==` in the case of my code so that "find" function works?
¿How can I use an `if` to see if my object is inside the vector?

For more context, I want to make the input (username, password) into an object and then compare to see if that object is inside the vector to log in, if not, create a new user.

First, this is my main code where I try to take an user and a password, then look inside a `vector` to see if the user is there to log in but if the user is not there I want to call a function that adds that user inside the vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "users.h"
using namespace std;


void NewUser(){
    StorageVector vec1;
    string username, password;
    cout << "-------- REGISTER NEW USER --------" << "----------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Give me the username: ";
    cin >> username;
    cout << "Give me your password: ";
    cin >> password;
    vec1.UsersDatabase.push_back(User(username, password));
}

int main(){
    StorageVector U1;

    string password, username;

    cout << "  STUDENTS MANAGEMENT SYSTEM " << endl;
    cout << "------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "            LOGIN              " << endl;
    cout << "--> Username: " << endl;
    cin >> username;
    cout << "--> Password: " << endl;
    cin >> password;
    auto it = find(U1.UsersDatabase.begin(), U1.UsersDatabase.end(), User(username,password) );
    if(it != U1.UsersDatabase.end()){
        cout << "User not found! redirecting..." << endl;
        NewUser();
    }

}
```

Then in my second file, my header file is where I have two classes, one for my object and one for my vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

//class for my object

class User{

    private:
        string username, password;

    public:
        User(string new_username, string new_password): username(new_username), password(new_password){}

};

class StorageVector{
    public:
        vector <User> UsersDatabase;
};
```

I would appreciate any feedback on what I did wrong c:

Comment: `find`: Use `std::find_if`.  Also, what makes two `User`'s equal?  That's the general reason why the compiler cannot do this -- there is no rules stating what makes one `User` equal to another `User`.

Comment: You need some way to compare `User` object for equality to be able to find it. Or use a [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) with [`std::find_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) (which is the solution I recommend in your case.

Comment: Most login programs search for a user name first, without checking password. If the user name is on file, then they check the password. That is why you cannot simply define the obvious `operator==` function inside class `User`. That function would typically compare both user name and password. Note the link between what you copy in a copy ctor and what you compare in an equality operator. Usually, they are the same. If you copy something, the copy should be equal to the original. So, I like the solution offered by @Some programmer dude: pass a lamda that makes the comparison you need.

Comment: Add `auto operator<=>(const User&) const = default;` to `User`.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo: would that mean that a new User was created whenever a user made a mistake entering his password?

Comment: @tbxfreeware The only thing adding `operator<=>` does is to make `User` instances comparable.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo, sorry for the confusion. The OP asks what operator he should add to make `find` work. If he adds the operator that you suggest, then his program will do what I said: it will add a new `User` whenever a password is incorrectly entered. But I'm sure you can see this from his code!

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik is right! @Jose Ignacio Contreras Mendez: You need to pass `U1` as a function argument to any function that needs it. Function `NewUser` should be declared as `void NewUser(StorageVector& vec1)`, and the declaration for a local variable `vec1` should be deleted.

Comment: @tbxfreeware Yes, that's true. The current code only tries to find a `User` comparing equal and that's what adding `operator<=>` will do. In order to deal with wrong passwords, OP would need to change the code.

Comment: A better way might be to use a `std::map` with the username as the key and the password as the value. You could search by username easily and then check the password. You have to figure out if this is a question about how to use `find` or how to solve your actual problem and `find` is not the solution you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have been trying to use find to look for an object inside a vector but it is telling me to overload an operator and I don´t know how

You could add an `operator==` function to class `User`, but it probably won't help you solve this problem. What you really need is a way to find a user based on his `username` alone. For that, I think the solution offered by @PaulMcKenzie and @Some programmer dude was the most direct.

Changing `find` to `find_if`, and using a lambda to check `username`, will give you this:

```cpp
    auto it = find_if(U1.UsersDatabase.begin(), U1.UsersDatabase.end(), 
        [&](User const& u) {
            return username == u.get_username();
        }
    );
```

So, that is the answer to your question. But that won't work by itself. In your `User` class, `username` is a private member. You need a public "getter" function to make it available. I added this function to class `User`. It is called by the lambda above.

```cpp
public:
    std::string get_username() const {
        return username;
    }
```

In addition, you need to pass a reference to `U1` to any function that needs it. Declaring a different `StorageVector` as a local variable inside function `NewUser` is wrong. `vec1` should be a reference parameter of function `NewUser`, not a local variable:

```cpp
void NewUser(StorageVector& vec1) {
    // ...
}
```

When you call `NewUser`, include `U1` as an argument: `NewUser(U1)`.

Finally, did you notice that your test `if (it != U1.UsersDatabase.end()) ...` is backwards? It should use `==` if you are trying to detect a new user.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH, IT REALLY HELPED ME TO HAVE MENTAL CLARITY!!!!!

Comment: @Jose Ignacio Contreras Mendez: It pleases me a lot to be able to help a programmer who is new to C++. Your question made that easy. All too often, the questions from beginners are inarticulate and unfocused. You new guys are the future, and we need to do whatever we can to support you.